# ObjectDisposedException when using extension method on RSAKeyValue

Tags: c#, cryptography, rsa, objectdisposedexception

I was trying to write the following simple extension method for [RSAKeyValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.xml.rsakeyvalue(v=VS.71).aspx):

```
public static class RSAKeyValueExtensions
{
    public static string ToXmlString(this RSAKeyValue keyValue)
    {
        return keyValue.GetXml().OuterXml;
    }
}
```

However, it seems whenever I use `ToXmlString`, I get an exception:

> System.ObjectDisposedException: Safe handle has been closed

Is there a way to encapsulate the `GetXml().OuterXml` so it isn't repeated in various places in my code without getting an `ObjectDisposedException`?

Comment: Can you show how you use this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the problem is that I was using an extension method, I think I was getting that exception because I was calling `GetXml()` on the `RSAKeyValue` instance after the underlying `RSACryptoServiceProvider` had already been disposed.